# Where in an Eclipse workspace is the list of projects stored?

Tags: eclipse, project

I use Eclipse with "external" projects - i.e. projects created from existing source.

Poking around in the workspace files, I cannot find any reference to these projects. My question is: how does Eclipse keep track of these projects?

I'd like to be able to add such a project to the workspace automatically (by generating `.project` and `.classpath` files).

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718456/create-an-eclipse-project-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Windows:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\
```

Linux / osx:

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/
```

Your project can exist outside the workspace, but all Eclipse-specific `metadata` are stored in that `org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects` directory
As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251116/where-in-an-eclipse-workspace-is-the-list-of-projects-stored/251129?noredirect=1#comment122812680_251129) by [tk421storm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2344699/tk421storm), and in [Jeegar Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775964/jeegar-patel)'s  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114078/6309):

> In order for manual changes to take effect, make sure to do `File -> Refresh` afterwards.

Comment: @RoboAlex I usually don't edit it directly, but add or remove projects from the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: The last path is `.projects` on my system (Mint 16); is it different on Windows?

Comment: @WChargin not sure, maybe it has changed more than 5 years later. Which Eclipse version are you using on Mint?

Comment: from Jeegar's answer below, in order for manual changes to take effect, make sure to do File -> Refresh afterwards.

Comment: @tk421storm Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 13):

In Mac OS X, it is under

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects
```

Answer (score 9):

In Eclipse 3.3:

It's installed under your Eclipse workspace. Something like:

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\
```

**within** your workspace folder.

Under that folder is one folder per project.
There's a file in there called *.location*, but it's binary.

So it looks like you can't do what you want, without interacting w/ Eclipse programmatically.

Comment: +1 for the pointer to .location. In my case, the workspace folder had **not** changed, but the (different) location where the projects lived: different drive letter. I ended up fixing these files in place with (D:->F:) `sfk replace -pat -binary _5552492F2F66696C653A2F443A2F_5552492F2F66696C653A2F463A2F_ -dir .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects -file .location`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Perforce (imported the project as a Perforce project), then .cproject and .project will be located under the root of the PERFORCE project, not on the workspace folder.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux after deleting

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\
```

Does not worked.

After that i have done **File->Refresh**

Then it cleared all old project listed from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have several workspaces - so you can connect to one and have set "A" of projects - and then connect to a different set when ever you like.