# Which configuration file contains the names of all projects in Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where in an Eclipse workspace is the list of projects stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251116/where-in-an-eclipse-workspace-is-the-list-of-projects-stored)

Is there any configuration file inside the workspace folder where Eclipse stores a list of all projects that belong to the workspace?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my eclipse I can find a folder for every project under:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/
```

Comment: On my system it's under `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/`.