# Headless build in Eclipse: how to retrieve result value

Tags: eclipse, scripting, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse CDT's headlessbuild feature for integrating Eclipse with TeamCity. I use a command line call to build my projects as descriped in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718456/create-an-eclipse-project-on-the-command-line). If there is a compilation error, a message box pops up saying "Java was started but returned exit code=1". I'd rather not have this message but get the return code so I can process it further in my script. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress the popup and redirect output to be included with your script:

- Add "--launcher.suppressErrors" to your command line arguments for eclipse

The error needs to be tracked down in the GUI from what I can tell, because the headless mode doesn't support very good error reporting from sub-tasks yet.

From there I used output from the GUI-based build to narrow down why my project failed to build.

Sources:

- http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg15343.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=481938&S=c88d71260a7d130eebdccb8f2e5537f2
- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=481938&S=c88d71260a7d130eebdccb8f2e5537f2
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=209080#c21