# Creation of php project in eclipse from command line

Tags: php, eclipse, command-line, project

Is there a way to create eclipse PHP project from command line? I am using Helios (PDT). (I know that it is possible for [JDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line) and [CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718456/create-an-eclipse-project-on-the-command-line))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDT has no command line options at all, especially none to create a project.