# eclipse import project using command line

Tags: eclipse

I want to create a script to checkout some projects from cvs and automatically import them into eclipse. I can checkout everything into the workspace folder, but the projects don't appear in eclipse. I have to manually import them. Is there a way to import the projects using the command line?

Thanks

Kelly

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718456/create-an-eclipse-project-on-the-command-line

Comment: This is not duplicate because in that question CDT was mentioned and solution depending on CDT was proposed and is currently the most voted for.

Answer (score 5):

You use the `-import` argument:

```
eclipse -nosplash 
    -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild 
    -import {[uri:/]/path/to/project} 
    -build {project_name | all} 
    -cleanBuild {projec_name | all}
```

This link to Eclipse documentation may be helpful:

[Checking out a project from a CVS repository](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-96.htm)

Comment: no it did not work... an exception happened and the project was not imported. The begining of the error on the log file is this... !SESSION 2012-01-18 16:25:03.424 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_30
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import ../../workspace/subwire/ -build all -cleanBuild all

Comment: Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import ../../workspace/subwire/ -build all -cleanBuild all

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-01-18 16:25:34.013
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild" could not be found in the registry.

Comment: I think its CSV format instead of cvs.
and you want to display data where? in your SQLite or anything else?

Comment: Hey Guys, any progress on that issue? I think lots of people would need it. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted something simple without any dependencies and a plugin seemed to be the best answer. I wrote one and posted it here:

https://github.com/seeq12/eclipse-import-projects-plugin

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach would be from Ant+Groovy:
First create a build.xml file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="default">  
<taskdef name="groovy"
         classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"
         classpath="/home/me/workspace/Groovy/lib/groovy-all-2.1.4.jar" />  
<target name="default">
    <groovy>
        bundle = org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.core.resources");
        resPlugin = bundle.loadClass("org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin");
        root =  resPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        project = root.getProject("new");
        project.create(null);
        project.open(null);
        resPlugin.getWorkspace().save(true, null);
    </groovy>
</target>
    </project>
```

Then run by executing:

```
./eclipse -nosplash -data /home/me/workspace -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile /home/me/build.xml
```

Of course, a full-fledged script will contain some more code, perhaps run using an [IWorkspaceRunnable](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_batching.htm?cp=2_0_10_9_0) and so on but the basics is here. Just be sure that any classes that you want to use from Eclipse are located using the Platform.getBundle + bundle.loadClass mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

With Eclipse 4.12, June 2019, seven years later... you do have project import by passing it as command-line argument!

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/images/pass-directory-to-launcher.png]

> You can import a project into Eclipse by passing its path as a parameter to the launcher.
>
> The command would look like:
>
> - `eclipse /path/to/project` on Linux and Windows, or
> - `open Eclipse.app -a /path/to/project` on macOS.

Comment: this is useful! but how can I make it also choose a project? Especially if there is only one project in the specified path.

Comment: @m4l490n I suppose all you need to do is to select the parent folder of that project.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @VonC there is a command line import for Windows and Linux. For those like me on MacOS, you may have noted that the instructions do not work.

There is an Open issue about this on github: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/.github/issues/149

the gist of it is the MacOS documentation is incorrect, it should be:

```
open Eclipse.app --args /path/to/project
```

Which does not work because of a bug, but at least is a command that does not crash. '-a' is no longer valid and causes the MacOS command to crash and not run Eclipse.

There is some other bug causing this not to actually work on MacOS as of 4.28 version of Eclipse.