# Import EMX into Eclipse via command line

Tags: java, eclipse, rational-rsa

I hope my question will be clear enough as I am not used to Eclipse environment.

My goal is to create a project in Eclipse with an already existing EMX file. I gather that file from a Git repository.

And I would like to create a command line (or a script, or anything I can run automatically from remote) that imports that EMX file into Eclipse, so I can use another script (already created) to work with this EMX.

My problem is that I don't know how to create this script or command line.

I've tried solutions found here at StackOverflow, without success. Maybe I'm just bad :p

As I am beginner in Eclipse stuff, if someone has a link to a clear tutorial or working example, it would be very nice.

Note: I just have the EMX file (no .project or whatever). So I guess I need to create a project with this file, and not just import an existing project.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Laurent

Comment: Show some of the solutions that you have tried.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your interest. I've first tried a solution like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718456/create-an-eclipse-project-on-the-command-line but I don't have CDT installed. Then I tried this solution to check whether I can use groovy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908219/eclipse-import-project-using-command-line but it doesn't work either. If I guess well, "root.getProject("new");" is trying to open an existing project named "new" and I want to create one. I did not fin in the documentation any method that would do what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do what I wanted by creating a plugin which imports projects from a given path into my current workspace.
Main part of the code is from: http://code.google.com/p/headlesseclipse/source/browse/branches/JUnit/com.ind.eclipse.headlesseclipse/src/com/ind/eclipse/headlessworkspace/HeadlessProjectImport.java?r=88
I did not find any way to do this outside the plugin. Grovvy solution was giving plenty of errors and without CDT, the first simple solution I looked for was not available.