# Import Eclipse PSF in command line

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to import a PSF containing SVN repository location in Eclipse.
With the IDE we can do this via File => Import
But I need to do this with command line (in order to install a full development environment automatically).
I've see this post : [eclipse import project using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908219/eclipse-import-project-using-command-line), but the response don't help me.

Have you any suggestion or solution for my problems?