# (MCUXpresso / Eclipse project with C) Automatic headless build

Tags: c, eclipse, shell

**Hi,**

Attached are the different steps to compile a project from scratch without a GUI in a container.

I built a Docker with MCUXpresso and after cloning this project I want to compile automatically like I was a developer.

For compilation, I have found this [article](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/08/03/building-eclipse-and-mcuxpresso-ide-projects-from-the-command-line/) , and [this](https://community.nxp.com/t5/LPCXpresso-IDE-FAQs/Building-projects-from-the-command-line/m-p/468047), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908219/eclipse-import-project-using-command-line).

For linkage problem, I have found this [article](https://community.nxp.com/t5/MCUXpresso-IDE/Trouble-with-headless-build-on-Jenkins-SDK-location-and-Linker/m-p/1021711/highlight/true).

**Everything works!**

*Step 1: How solve linkage problem.*

You need to install the SDK package. Otherwise copy to your container.

```
docker cp </path/mcuxpresso/sdk/uc.zip> <container_name:/root/mcuxpresso/02/SDKPackages/>
```

[image: SDK Package]

*Step 2 : Import a SDK example hello world project*

[image: MCUXpresso create a simple project via MCUXpresso]

*Step 3 : Copy this project in your docker.*

```
docker cp <</source/path>> <<container_name:/destination/path>>
```

*Step 4 : Update path of IDE.*

```
export IDE=/usr/local/mcuxpressoide/ide/mcuxpressoide
```

[image: Add IDE path]

*Step 5 : Compile.*

```
$IDE -nosplash
        --launcher.suppressErrors
        -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild
        -data \path\to\workspace
        -import {[uri:/]/path\to\project}
        -build {project_name[/build_config] | all}
        -cleanBuild {project_name[/build_config] | all}
```

[image: Compilation OK]

*Step 6 : Finished.*

[image: Everything works.]

Comment: Installing MCUXpresso IDE requires interacting with the installer to accept the license agreement.   Did you install both MCUXpresso IDE and SDK in Docker container or only the SDK?

Comment: Yes. Installed in a docker. I don't remeber how but I find it in google. I will check next day the "magic" code for do it that.

Comment: Gromph, clues on "magic" code you used to automated MCUXpresso installer in Docker would be *very* much appreciated.  Thank you in advance for checking !

Comment: Done since Feb 17. Check answer, hope it works.

Comment: The Eclipse runtime options: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

Answer (score 1):

**Install MCUXpresso in Docker:**

Preliminary step: Need download MCUXpresso before launch docker build.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
LABEL Description="Image for buiding arm project with mcuxpresso"
WORKDIR  /usr/src/mcuxpresso

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV IDE_VERSION 11.0.0_2516

COPY mcuxpresso/mcuxpressoide-${IDE_VERSION}.x86_64.deb.bin /usr/src/mcuxpresso

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y \
    # Development files
    whiptail \
    build-essential \
    bzip2 \
    libswt-gtk-3-jni \
    libswt-gtk-3-java \
    wget && \
    apt clean

# Install mcuxpresso
RUN chmod a+x mcuxpressoide-${IDE_VERSION}.x86_64.deb.bin &&\
  # Extract the installer to a deb package
  ./mcuxpressoide-${IDE_VERSION}.x86_64.deb.bin --noexec --target mcu &&\
  cd mcu &&\
  dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update &&\
  apt-get install -y libusb-1.0-0-dev dfu-util libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libncurses5:i386 udev &&\
  dpkg -i --force-depends JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb &&\
  # manually install mcuxpressoide - post install script fails
  dpkg --unpack mcuxpressoide-${IDE_VERSION}.x86_64.deb &&\
  rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/mcuxpressoide.postinst -f &&\
  dpkg --configure mcuxpressoide &&\
  apt-get install -yf &&\
  # manually run the postinstall script
  mkdir -p /usr/share/NXPLPCXpresso &&\
  chmod a+w /usr/share/NXPLPCXpresso &&\
  ln -s /usr/local/mcuxpressoide-${IDE_VERSION} /usr/local/mcuxpressoide

ENV TOOLCHAIN_PATH /usr/local/mcuxpressoide/ide/tools/bin
ENV PATH $TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH    

RUN rm mcuxpressoide-${IDE_VERSION}.x86_64.deb.bin
RUN rm -rf mcu
```

Comment: Thank you!
https://gist.github.com/mneil/f0894b715c43a5387b15a30afd7015e1