# Add android eclipse library to unity3d project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have an android library in the form of an eclipse project that I want to integrate with unity3d. I know I can make a jar from eclipse and drop it in unity's plugins/android folder. However as I understand it that necessarily strips out the resources from the project.

If I export the unity game to an eclipse project, I can right-click and add the android project as a library. However I don't like this approach because it doesn't fit with our current automation process - which basically just script's unity's build dialog.

I'd like a way to tell unity that I want this eclipse project linked as an android library on export. Does anyone know a way to do that, or how to pack the resources into the jar or another way of getting this stuff to talk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real answer I've found is that in 4.2, you can drop an eclipse project in plugins/android and it will be linked correctly. Just have to hang on I suppose. :-/

Comment: ...and now we're on 4.3 and this process works fine.

Comment: can you elaborate what you do? Do you drop your entire project into the plugins/android folder (so that you have a structure plugins/android/MyProject/res, for example), or do you copy the res folder straight into the /plugins/android folder (so that you have a plugins/android/res structure)?

Comment: the former. the entire project into the plugins folder.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to go is using Unity's [Build Player Pipeline](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html). Depending on the platform you are working on you then have to set up a shell script or do your stuff in C#.

It's some year ago that I were a Java/Eclipse expert as I am working on iOS now. The Android Developers page shows some way to [manipulate projects via command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html).

Maybe the better way to go is using Eclipse switches like --import (s. 1st answer in [Create an Eclipse project on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718456/create-an-eclipse-project-on-the-command-line) and the link provided) but on the other hand I can't find the switch in the [help pages](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html).

Well, not really a *bounty answer* but maybe some inspiration :-)