# Programmatically list open projects in an eclipse workspace from outside of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, workspace

I want to write a Gradle plugin which can inspect an eclipse workspace directory and iterate over the open projects within the workspace and determine the location of each.

Something like

```
Workspace workspace = EclipseUtils.parseWorkspace("c:/myEclipseWorkspace");
Collection<Project> projects = workspace.getProjects();
for (Project project : projects) {
   System.out.println(String.format("name=%s, location=%s, open=%s",
      project.getName(), project.getLocation(), project.isOpen()));
}
```

I've looked at my workspace and can see some `.location` files under `c:\myEclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\`

But these files are a custom binary format
    [image]

Is there an eclipse API that I can invoke to parse these? Or some other solution to iterate the open projects in a workspace.

Please note that I want to do this externally to eclipse and NOT within an eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 5):

### Reading the Private Description to Obtain Location

Since you are writing in Java, then reuse the Eclipse code from your external location.

i.e. Pull out some of the key code from `org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin`. Start with the impl of `org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()` and then work your way to `org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot.getProjects()`

The above code reads the project description here: `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.readPrivateDescription(IProject, ProjectDescription)` and that is called from `org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(IProject, boolean)` which has some logic about default locations.

This is the joy of EPL, as long as your new program/feature is EPL you can reuse Eclipse's core code to do new and wonderful things.

### Reading Workspace State to Obtain Open/Close State

When reading workspace state, you are moving into the [ElementTree](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/watson/ElementTree.java?id=203adc38703c15ee3fa52113131811962dd336e2#n23) data structures. Reading this without using the ElementTree classes is probably unrealistic. Using the ElementTree classes without full OSGi is probably unrealistic. I provide the following notes to help you on your way.

Working backwards:

- [`ICoreConstants.M_OPEN`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/ICoreConstants.java?id=203adc38703c15ee3fa52113131811962dd336e2#n33) is the flag value indicating project is open or closed (set for open, clear for closed)
- M_OPEN is tested when [`Project.isOpen()`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/Project.java?id=203adc38703c15ee3fa52113131811962dd336e2#n883) is called
- The flags at runtime are in [`ResourceInfo.flags`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/ResourceInfo.java?id=203adc38703c15ee3fa52113131811962dd336e2#n42)
- The flags are loaded by [`ResourceInfo.readFrom()`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/ResourceInfo.java?id=203adc38703c15ee3fa52113131811962dd336e2#n310) called from [`SaveManager.readElement()`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/SaveManager.java?id=203adc38703c15ee3fa52113131811962dd336e2#n539)
- The [`DataInput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) `input` passed to `readElement` is from the Element Tree stored in the workspace meta directory in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/<id>.tree`. The specific version (id) of the file to use is recorded in the safe table `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable/org.eclipse.core.resources`
- The safe table is part of the `SaveManager`'s internal state stored in a [`MasterTable`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.resources.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/SaveManager.java?id=203adc38703c15ee3fa52113131811962dd336e2#n37)

Comment: PS. I look forward to seeing what you come up with (and am very intrigued by your direction)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since you're intrigued, [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/big-multi-module-project-open-only-needed-module-in-ide/12836) is the end goal

Comment: This is proving very difficult to isolate the code responsible for parsing the `.location` file. Any more pointers would be much appreciated. This would be soooooo much simpler if they were xml / json

Comment: Added some more pointers. Most stuff in Eclipse is xml (sometimes xml serialized into other xml files). Of course most of this code started before json was coined! I don't know why this particular bit of code is not xml.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to parse the file using [this](https://github.com/gensth/ProjectLocationUpdater/blob/master/plugins/com.github.eclipse.projectlocationupdater.plugin/src/com/github/eclipse/projectlocationupdater/LocationUpdater.java) as a reference

```
    protected Location parseLocation(File locationFile) throws IOException {
        String name = locationFile.getParentFile().getName();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(locationFile));
        try {
            in.skip(ILocalStoreConstants.BEGIN_CHUNK.length);
            String path = in.readUTF();
            int numRefs = in.readInt();
            String[] refNames = new String[numRefs];
            for (int i = 0; i < numRefs; ++ i) {
                refNames[i] = in.readUTF();
            }
            in.skipBytes(ILocalStoreConstants.END_CHUNK.length);
            return new Location(name, path, refNames);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be able to detect if a project is closed or not. Any pointers on getting the closed flag would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm going to have to leave you there. You have figured out loads already, and I don't "just know" this stuff. As for the closed or not, sounds like a new question would be a good idea, maybe more people will see it again?

Comment: The project info like that is generally stored under in the workspace `.metadata` directory, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119149/639520 . It's binary data, though so it's not clear where the open/closed state is stored within there (or even if it is). For that level of detail you might have to ask on the Eclipse forums or dive into the Eclipse resources code.

Comment: I have noticed (with Eclipse Oxygen) that a project is closed if and only if the corresponding project folder (inside `.projects`) contains a file called `1.tree`.

Comment: Thanks @lodovik, I guess I could take a copy of the `.metadata` directory before/after closing a project and do a diff of the two. These 1.tree files should show up as well as anything else