# Can Eclipse Neon determinate the projects I don't need for developement?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-rcp, gradle-eclipse

I'm working on a rather big RCP application, where only 2 / 100 projects are written and maintained by me. I do have dependencies on other projects and these projects might depend on another project as well.
Since Eclipse takes a lot of time to start up and loading (might even crashing sometimes if not ready) I was wondering if Eclipse Neon could determinate the projects I don't need so I could wipe them out of the workspace to fasten up the loading.
If it is helpful: We use `gradle` to build the project.

Comment: A possible idea would be to run the application with a coverage report, but I guess there are more elegant ways.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly how your projects relate to one another but I'm guessing you could use gradle's new [composite build support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) (added in v3.1) to have some projects as source dependencies and others as binary dependencies.

You could then wipe out everything that's not part of the composite build from your eclipse workspace. You might even make use of [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33831466/1089967) to see what source folders are in your eclipse workspace... perhaps you could write a gradle task to do the wiping?

I'm assuming you are using [buildship](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship)?

Comment: We're using buildship, but on gradle version `2.11`, which will probably stick with us for a while, nice idea though!