# How to Move and organize eclipse projects and workspaces?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, organization

Seems like one can [move an eclipse project to a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479466/moving-project-to-another-folder-in-eclipse). This leaves the original project available in the original workspace. Seems like you need to delete the project from the old workspace and then import the project from it's new location (my new workspace is where i moved the project to). I have about couple hundred of so projects (mostly java) in a dozen or so workspaces. So this is sorta *painful* given how slow eclipse starts up these days.

Is there any may to automate this? Seems like i could import all of the projects into the new workspace, but that's about it.

Also, it looks like one can move workspaces around provided one moves the /metadata. Is this safe?

How do people organize a large number of eclipse projects?

Edit: Seems like each project has a [.location file with an URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119008/where-are-project-stored-in-eclipse) that points to where the project really lives. So perhaps one could move *all* of the projects to a single directory (assuming no name conflicts), delete all of the workspaces,, maybe rearrange the projects into different folders, create new workspaces and import the projects into the workspaces that you want them in?

Comment: Can you give more details? What OS are you on? So you want to move all projects from a dozen workspaces into one? Why?

Comment: windows 8.1 with cygwin installed