# Eclipse and subversion/git - which files to keep

Tags: eclipse, git, svn

I've just ported a C++ system from codeblocks to eclipse.  I now wish to put the workspace under source code control.  I don't know if I have set this up correctly.  The directory structure looks like

```
toplevel
+--.metadata
   +--very big file structure
+--project1
   +--.project
   +--.cproject
   +--various cpp/h files
+--project2
   +--.project
   +--.cproject
   +--various cpp/h files
```

What I would like is to be able to checkout everything on a different machine, start up eclipse, point it to the workspace and pick up all the projects.  I know I have to keep the .project and .cproject files but what do I need to keep in .metadata or have I got the entire structure wrong?

**Edit** I found [Where in an Eclipse workspace is the list of projects stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251116/where-in-an-eclipse-workspace-is-the-list-of-projects-stored) which recommends .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects but there is a structure under each project folder containing .markers .indexes and properties.index.  Do all these need to be kept?  I had a bad experience with codeblocks where I kept the layout file and even though I finally deleted it, it was stuck in the source code control system forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would discourage you from putting `.metadata` folder into source code repository. It is a very complex and large folder that contains internal plug-in data. It is *very* hard to keep it in the repository.

The recommended way is to store only the project folders (`project1` and `project2`) in the repo along with `.project`, `.cproject` and `.settings`. You can then import them using [subversion](http://help.collab.net/topic/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/checkout.html) or [git](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories) on any other machine.

Comment: I probably need to store something in *.metadata*.  If I just store .project and .cproject, I can't load the workspace from eclipse on a different machine.  I'm running experiments to figure out what will reload the workspace.

Comment: You are better off just sharing _projects_ from workspace not entire workspace. This is how most people use Eclipse: create a fresh workspace on another machine and import your projects into it.

Comment: This will work for small systems which have about 5 projects.  The problem is there are about 25 projects: combination of libs, DLLs and executables.  Development systems like Visual Studio and Codeblocks can keep all the projects in one solution.  I'm just looking for the eclipse equivalent.

Comment: Did a few experiments but couldn't figure out which files in .metadata reproduced the workspace.  I just saved the .project and .cproject files then imported from the top level directory and it picked up all the projects which is basically what I wanted but in 2 steps instead of 1.